# How to free up memory after running a process in a shell

Tags: bash, shell, memory

I have a script that runs a JAVA process that loads data into a database every 10 secs using a loop. This script seems to work perfectly, but after a couple of days I start getting Memory issues. If I stop the script everything frees up, I can start it again and it will run happily for another couple of days.

```
RUNME=Y
PROPERTIES=someproprties.properties
CHECKFILE=somelockfile.lock
touch $CHECKFILE

while [ "$RUNME" = "Y" ]; do
  if [ -f $CHECKFILE ]
  then

   #Run Process
   $DR_HOME/bin/dr -cp $CP_PLUGIN -Xmx64g --engine parallelism=1 --runjson $HOME_DIR/workflows/some_dataflow.dr --overridefile $PROPERTIES 1> /dev/null 2>> $LOG_FILE

   #Give Process a little time to finish up before moving on
   sleep 10s

  else
    RUNME=N
  fi
done
```

I had assumed that once the process had run it would make any memory that it had allocated for the process available again, so that the next iteration of the loop could use this. Given that this does not seem to be the case, is there a way I can force the release of memory post the running the process. I appreciate that this may be something that I need to address in the actual JAVA Process rather than in a Shell - but as this is the area I have more control over, I thought I would at least ask.

Comment: Nahuel - I have corrected - the error was in my typing of the question not in the actual script that runs.

Comment: ok, on which OS?

Comment: The script is running on Linux LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5

Comment: I don't see anything in that script that would use memory itself. The `if` statement isn't actually necessary; you can use `while [ -f "$CHECKFILE" ]; do`, and run `dr` and `sleep` directly in the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: Since you are running on Linux, it might be worth looking at `inotifywait` instead of polling for the file:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html

Answer (score 0):

To check the processes which are running and memory used

```
sid=$(ps -p $$ -osid=)

while ....

    ps --sid $sid -opid,tty,cpu,vsz,etime,command
```

`vsz` shows the virtual size used by the process

Then if it's really bash process, it may be environment which is growing, but from the script it can't be that.

Comment: I added this - and the vsz figures shown are consistent through all iterations - which suggests there is no issue with the script. However I also added a `free -m` command, and this shows a consistent drop of 15mg memory every iteration. If I stop the process and start it again, the memory free goes back up to where it was, and then starts its gradual descent again - so clearly when this process is being set off in a loop it holds onto something - which to me seem like an issue with the shell execution, not the process.

Comment: It shows 2 processes, the underlying shell pid and the ps command: `34754 ?          - 106104       00:22 /bin/bash ./dl_Reverb.sh
36020 ?          - 108136       00:00 ps --sid 34753 -opid
`

Comment: otherwise running `top` in another term, shows the processes using the most the cpu and typing `>` sorts by memory (the next column on the right)